# Not able to select popup box fields and options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

jquery:

```
$("#type_name").click(function(){
            $("body").append('<div class="modalOverlay">');
            $("#add_form").fadeIn(1000);
            $("#first_name").val("");
            $("#email").val("");
            $("#phone_no").val("");
            $("#mobile").val("");
            positionPopup('#add_form');
            $("#first_name").focus();
        });
```

css:

```
.modalOverlay {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    opacity: .4;

    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

html for popup box:

```
<div id="add_form" style="display:none">
    <form id="form"  method="post" action="." onsubmit="return form_validate()">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <h2> Choose Follower Name</h2>
        <br />
        <table  width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="width:100px;">First name:</td><td><input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" maxlength="20"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Email:</td><td><input type="text" name="email" maxlength="36" id="email"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Daytime phone:</td><td><input type="text" name="phone" maxlength="15" id="phone_no" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Mobile phone:</td><td><input type="text" name="mobile" maxlength="15" id="mobile" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="display:none;color:red" id="warning"><td colspan="2" align="center" >All fields are manditory</td></tr>
        </table>
        <div style="width:180px;margin:20px 5px 0 10px" align="right">

            <button style="margin-right:10px;" type="button" class="close" name="cancel" class="forward backicon">
                <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/button-icon-ir-back.png" width="12" height="17" alt="" />
            Cancel</button>   {% include "buttons/add.html" %}
        </div>
```

While displaying the popup,to hide the background modalOverlay css i used.I am able to hide the background but i am not able to select any option or field in popup box.

Thanks

Comment: Check if the popup box is behind the overlay. Sounds like a z-index issue.

Comment: yes,popup is behind Overlay

Comment: Okay set the z-index property of the popup box such that it's greater than the z-index of the overlay

Comment: @anpsmn dont set the z-index, do it through your jQuery by addClass. Also, I wouldnt append this if you dont have to, I would code it to the site, and set its display to none, then reveal it. IMO

Comment: For popup box i am not using css,so how to set z-index

Comment: @Cam Yes, I was asking to set through CSS. My bad, I wasn't clear before.

Comment: @user2086641 Well then you need to give a style for popup in CSS. You can refer [bootstrap modal](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals) and see what styles are given to the box and the overlay.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the z-index to your modalOverlay class selector:

```
.modalOverlay {
z-index: 9999;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
opacity: .4;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);}
```

I used 9999 for the `z-index` value, but it can be any number, as long no other element has a higher `z-index` value. Another thing to consider is that z-index applys only to elements with position `absolute`, `relative` or `fixed` like yours.

Out of topic, but still relevant for your problem, if you set `opacity` .4 to your modalOverlay, everything in it will have an `opacity` of .4 too. I don't belive that's what your trying to achieve. Forgive me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Background is perfect,not able to select or click the field in popup box

Comment: If you can't click on the field, it can be because there's something transparent above it. It can be another element, a margin of another element, etc. Anyway there's something above your popup box. Are you using firebug or other in browser inspector?